# Understanding VIM: Automagically (Automatic and Magical) transform markdown to html

Tags: vim, editor, markdown

I'm on the process of studying vim and its inner workings. While strolling by the deep depths of the Internet I stumbled into this [article](http://blog.sanctum.geek.nz/vim-koans/), one section discusses how to transform markdown into html automatically:

> “See, master,” he said, “I have nearly finished the Vim macros that translate Markdown into HTML. My functions interweave, my parser is a paragon of efficiency, and the results nearly flawless. I daresay I have mastered Vimscript, and my work will validate Vim as a modern editor for the enlightened developer! Have I done rightly?”
>
> Master Wq read the acolyte’s code for several minutes without saying anything. Then he opened a Markdown document, and typed:
>
> :%!markdown
>
> HTML filled the buffer instantly. The acolyte began to cry.

I tried this by first installing markdown, `sudo apt-get install -y markdown`... after this opened vim and typed some markdown:

```
# Hello
This is just a test

    public class Main {
            public static void main(String[] args) {
            }
    }
```

then typed: `:%!markdown`, suddenly this appeared:

```
<h1>Hello</h1>

<p>This is just a test</p>

<pre><code>    public class Main {
            public static void main(String[] args) {
            }
    }
</code></pre>
```

My observation: `markdown` parses markdown and outputs html, so the mystery lies in `:%!`, can anyone enlighten me on this?

BTW, Vim is great.. you should try it!

Comment: Have a look at `:h :%` and `:h :!`.

Comment: @Marth ah ok, `:%` is a selector and `:!` executes an external command, this will change whatever is selected I guess (tried an !ls and this changed whatever is selected in Visual Mode), but one question how does this chaining work? nifty feature, will use it more often...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filtering is an extremely common unix pattern which consist of manipulating the output of a command before passing it to another command.

`:%!markdown` means "open a sub-shell, pass the whole content of the current buffer to the `stdin` of the `markdown` program and replace the whole buffer with whatever comes out of its `stdout`.

Comment: thanks, is there any material you can suggest? preferably free online resources, since I have no money for books

Comment: @IrvinDenzelTorcuato: The usual recommendation is to go through `vimtutor` a couple of times, until you feel you've mastered (most of) what's in it. Aside from that, the built-in help (accessed via `:help <topic>`) is really great.

Comment: @Marth I do try to read on `:help` and dig some `man` pages, but they look and feel too complicated for me